# How to change title of PDF fetched from backend and displayed on the react page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, axios, react-component

I am fetching the pdf from backend and showing it in the component.

The functionality looks like this:

```
axios(`${apiURL}/pdf`, {
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'blob' //Force to receive data in a Blob Format
})
.then(response => {
//Create a Blob from the PDF Stream
    const file = new Blob(
      [response.data], 
      {type: 'application/pdf'});
//Build a URL from the file
    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
//Open the URL on new Window
    window.open(fileURL);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

However the problem is that when you open that component in the top part of the pdf it shows random numbers on the left of the PDF pages number, which is probably string generated with createObjectURl. How can I change it and display custom title or parameter from react router?

Comment: How about `window.open(\`${apiURL}/pdf\`)`

Comment: The point is that I am embeding it inside the component. Route is custom. The PDF container shows the title of random string with numbers inside the embed so that should be customized.

Comment: What do you mean, "embedding it inside the component"? Aren't you putting it in a new window?

Comment: No, I am using inside embed tags

Comment: Anyway even if you open it in a new tab problem will remain that title inside PDF container that should be customized :D

Comment: Ok, I'm not going to pretend I understand how that works. Regardless, the title of the PDF should be the filename, which can be set from the backend.